# Was the IMF complicit in destroying the Romanian economy?

Tags: europe, cold-war, communism, romania

Wikipedia claims that despite the unprecedented growth of Romanian industry and food and production at the rate of 22% per year, Romania experienced serious shortage of food and petrol in the late 80s which led to the collapse of the government. It also claims that it was due to the necessity of repaying the heavy debt to the IMF and in general, due to Ceaușescu's policy of collaboration with the IMF and the World Bank.

I want to know to what extent cooperation with the IMF was complicit in the collapse of the consumer sector of the Romanian economy in the 1980s.

Comment: A link to the wikipedia claim might be helpful here.

Answer (score 9):

The IMF wasn't complicit in it at all, it merely lent Ceaușescu's government money to invest in industrialisation - the investment of which which was mismanaged. Did Ceaușescu have to continue austerity measures despite the loans having been repaid to the IMF? IF so how is the IMF complicit? For demanding those loans be repaid?

Look to Ceaușescu's inefficient handling of government and industrial investment (and likely financial embezzlement) as the prime cause and not the IMF.